# Naming columns from other tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Just a quick question about naming columns that come from other tables, below i have the tables put in the SQL statement but after it I put an abbreviated version "MO" is this correct/ will this work in all situations or should i just stick to the full version like module.mod_code?

```
SELECT MO.MOD_CODE, MO.MOD_NAME, MO.ECTS_UNITS,MO.DESCRIPTION
FROM MODULE MO, SYLLABUS SY, PROGRAMME PR
WHERE MO.MOD_CODE = SY.MOD_CODE
AND SY.PROG_CODE = PR.PRO_CODE
AND PR.NFQ_LEVEL = ‘LEVEL 9’
AND MO.DESCRIPTION LIKE ‘%RESEARCH%’ OR DESCRIPTION LIKE ‘%QUALATIVE%’ OR DESCRIPTION LIKE     ‘%QUANTITATIVE%’;
```

Thanks :)

Comment: No. Beacuse QUALATIVE isn't a word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *cannot* stick to the full version.  Once you have given a table or subquery an alias, that is the name of that object in the scope of the query.  Actually, what happens is that the table name *becomes* the table alias, so you can use it for qualifying columns in the table.

You should also learn proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.  I am also guessing that you are missing parentheses on your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT MO.MOD_CODE, MO.MOD_NAME, MO.ECTS_UNITS,MO.DESCRIPTION
FROM MODULE MO JOIN
     SYLLABUS SY
     ON MO.MOD_CODE = SY.MOD_CODE JOIN
     PROGRAMME PR
     ON SY.PROG_CODE = PR.PRO_CODE
WHERE PR.NFQ_LEVEL = 'LEVEL 9' AND
      (MO.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%RESEARCH%' OR
       MO.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%QUALATIVE%' OR
       MO.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%QUANTITATIVE%'
      );
```

If you attempted something like `SELECT MODULE.MOD_CODE` in this query, it would return an error, because the table alias `MODULE` is not assigned to any object.

Comment: If in the case i was to use SELECT MODULE.MOD_MOD CODE
FROM MODULE, that would work then?

Comment: @Zinconium . . . That would work, because you haven't assigned an alias to `MODULE` so the table name itself would be the alias.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you're trying to reference columns using the table alias, and are wondering if there is any difference in using MO.[column] and module.[column]?

If that is the case, it is preferred to use the table alias to reference the column. This is because you may join back to the same table to retrieve a different subset of data. If you do this, you will need to define which set you want the data to come from.

Module AS M ---- Programme AS P  ------ Module AS SUBM